# How to open Terminal inside Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

How to open Terminal inside Eclipse Neon windows 10?

I follow  this steps

Windows show view  other and I couldn't find it

I clicked <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>CTL</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and nothing happened

I search for it in quick search

any advise?

Comment: did you ensure that the terminal plugin is installed? (Help -> installation details -> type "terminal" into the filter text)

Comment: In my eclipse it's called TM Terminal. I can't find anything about "terminal control". If you didn't manage to find TM Terminal in your installation it could be a good idea to install it (should be possible via the eclipse marketplace).

Comment: You can [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44220993/how-to-run-system-shell-terminal-inside-eclipse), proposed by [Filipe Luchini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1984854/filipe-luchini) or [install a Terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55732635/4575793) like [TM Terminal](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/tm-terminal) or [EasyShell](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/easyshell) if eclipse doesn't yet contain a terminal plugin. My version is more recent and already contained a terminal emulator.

Answer (score 24):

Simple Solution:

1. In Eclipse, `Help` --> `Eclipse Marketplace` --> type `terminal` in `find`
2. Install [`TM Terminal ...`](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/tm-terminal)
3. Restart Eclipse
4. `Window` --> `Show View` --> `Terminal`

Comment: or just hit Crtl + alt + T

Comment: or control + option + T for mac

Answer (score 7):

**Press Ctrl+Alt+T, or right-click and select Show In Local Terminal > Terminal.**

If you don't find there than you have to install TM local Terminal in your Eclipse.

**Here the Steps for download.**

Click on the Help from the top menu in Eclipse and select ‘Install New Software..‘
[image]

In some Eclipse packages, like STS or Eclipse for JEE Developers, the Terminal is already installed in your IDE. If not, you can install the TM Terminal from the Eclipse */release update site, as you can see in the image below.

```
http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen
```

[image]

[image]

Then, the terminal will open in a new view inside Eclipse.right-click and select Show In Local Terminal > Terminal.

Comment: For me, **Ctrl + Alt + Shift + T** worked.

_Note: TM Terminal should be installed for this to work._

Answer (score 4):

This

> Window --> Show View --> Terminal

works works for me.

But if it dosn't, you should try to install the terminal in the marketplace:

Help -> Eclipse Marketplace

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Click on the computer icon
Then select local terminal.