# How to run system shell/terminal inside Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, shell, terminal

I am using Eclipse Neon, and I would like to execute system commands on a shell/terminal, inside Eclipse.

In particular, I will need to open the system shell using the path of the current project folder on which I'm working in Eclipse.

Comment: It would be wise to called as specific title like this : `How to run system shell/terminal as  default with project path inside Eclipse?`

It's seem to be duplicate of earlier question [How to open Terminal inside Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43623643/how-to-open-terminal-inside-eclipse)

Answer (score 76):

In some Eclipse packages, like STS or Eclipse for JEE Developers, the Terminal is already installed in your IDE. If not, you can install the **TM Terminal** from the Eclipse */release update site, as you can see in the image below.

[image]

To open the command prompt (shell or terminal) using the path of a project directory inside Eclipse, you just need to select the folder, and press Ctrl+Alt+T, or right-click and select **Show In Local Terminal > Terminal**.

Then, the terminal will open in a new view inside Eclipse.

[image]

Comment: This option isn't present in all Eclipse installs as it isn't part of the core Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks @greg-449, I updated the answer as suggested.

Comment: @greg-449  Why they don't put a way to use jshell in Eclipse by default?

Comment: @johnny You would have to ask Eclipse development that, I am just a user.

Comment: @johnny Eclipse has had a core feature for a while called 'scrapbook' pages where you can enter and run arbitrary Java statements outside of a Class and execute them, similar to jshell. In a way this is more powerful than jshell because you can edit and rerun the statements in the editor as you can for any code

Comment: Easiest way: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/tm-terminal just drag and drop the install button to eclipse workspace.

Comment: Not all the versions of eclipse support drag and drop from marketplace to the IDE.  For example, these ones don't: https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/

Comment: improved comment: 
Not all the versions of eclipse support drag and drop from marketplace to the IDE.  For example, the developer build for developers that build eclipse ones don't: https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/. 
For normal users, you are right: all the eclipse versions you can download from the download packages page (https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/) have the marketplace client (org.eclipse.epp.mpc).

Answer (score 21):

The Eclipse IDE which I am working there is no Terminal is there. So I needed to add the plug in like this and it works fine when you try clicking <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Click on Help in Eclipse-->Eclipse Marketplace--> in Find box (Search terminal and Enter)--> You will see TM Terminal 4.0 Version and just install it.

You may need to restart afterwards

And finally you will be able to get the Terminal when you will type

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on Console.

Comment: Use CTRL-ALT-SHIFT-T to choose which type of Terminal to run.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have the `TM Terminal` plugin installed, you could use external run configurations.

Click on the arrow near run button with the toolbox and add a new external run configuration.
[image: external run configurations]

Here, you can enter the path of your program(if you want to run commands, it will be `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` (or the path to PowerShell on windows and `/bin/bash` (or similar if you use another shell) on linux.
[image: select cmd]

In this dialog, you can also specify running directory of the application(the current project in your case)

After that, you can save this configuration and start it using the external run configuration menu(run button with toolbox)

Answer (score 2):

Go to Window > show view > Other.
A dialog will show up, type Terminal in the search field, select Terminal and click open.
[image]
A new empty view will show up in Eclipse.
On the top right corner of the view there is a button Labeled "open a Terminal".
[image]
Click on it, a dialog will show up

[image]

click OK and there you go, you got a Terminal.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Click on Run Cofiguration--> arguments --> Program Arguments (write any number of String) -->click on run