# Java Add Terminal/command line to Eclipse console

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line, console

It is possible to add a command line / terminal to run inside of a Eclipse console?
Any help to find how to do this?

I want to use a IOConsole or IConsole or something like this to run a terminal inside a console in my app.

what i want is to run my application and inside my java application have a Console with a terminal..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run system shell/terminal inside Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44220993/how-to-run-system-shell-terminal-inside-eclipse)

Comment: what i want is to run my application and inside my java application have a Console with a terminal and not a terminal running in Eclipse IDE

Answer (score 0):

From the menu:
Window -> Show View -> Console

Comment: No what i want is to run my application and inside my java application have a Console with a terminal..